# Using radio buttons with multiple windows

Tags: python, tkinter

For my course work I am creating a program in python to help GCSE maths students revise, currently I have created multiple windows including a login, main menu, scoreboard and now a settings window. I wish to use radio buttons to allow the user to select various options such as the colour, this is where my problem begins, I am struggling to be able to set up my radio buttons so that you can only select one, I have made two radio buttons, one should change the background colour to blue and the other green, although when the program is being run I am able to select both radio buttons. I believe the problem is they aren't connected to the same variable and are not passing this value to that variable.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my code for the radio buttons]

[image: A screenshot of me being able to select both radiobuttons]

```
self.radiov = IntVar
self.rbcolour_blue = Radiobutton(self.master, text = "Blue", variable = self.radiov, value = 1, bg = "green", command = update_colour)
self.rbcolour_blue.place(x = 10, y = 60)
elf.rbcolour_green = Radiobutton(self.master, text = "Green", variable = self.radiov, value = 2, bg = "green", command = update_colour)
self.rbcolour_green.place(x = 10, y = 85)
```

Comment: Please post the code you've used to create the radio buttons

Comment: I think it's because you're missing the `()` on `IntVar()` for `self.radiov = IntVar`

Comment: I have just added the () at the end and it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntVar` is a class. You need to create instances of the class. Change this line:

```
self.radiov = IntVar
```

... to this:

```
self.radiov = IntVar()
```